# Makefile modify dependencies as its running

Tags: makefile, dependencies

What I want to do is:

```
$(UNTAR_MARKER): $(TARFILE)
    tar -xjkf $(TARFILE)
    touch $(UNTAR_MARKER)

%.installed : %.untarred
    dowork $^ $@

install: ????
```

Where `????` would be a list of some of the *.untarred files from the tarfile (I have a shell command which can generate the list, but it only works after the file has been untarred).  The issues here are:

1) I don't want to do a tar -tf, as this is a large tarfile, and I don't want to run tar twice.

2) I'd like to avoid a for loop in the code that loops through each files (this cannot take advantage of concurrency, and it complicates the makefile as the tar file is somewhat dynamic -- third parties can easily add files to it, and I don't want to process the old files)

3) I'd like to avoid untarring while the makefile is doing parsing, as that's just plain ugly

I'm wondering if it there's a simple way to create the dependency list dynamically, and modify it after a rule is run.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here but this sounds like something that included makefiles can help with. See [`3.5 How Makefiles Are Remade`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) for information about how that works.

Comment: Interesting...  So basically, I could have a rule that says the current makefile is dependent on the UNTAR_MARKER rule.  After the untar has occurred, the current Makefile is reparsed.  If the `????` is expanded to `$(shell find . -name *.untarred | sed s/untarred/installed/)` then this shell command would be rerun with the updated file system...  I'm wondering what happens with phony targets in this case -- are they rerun?   I'll have to play with this..

Comment: Something like that, yes. Though I would dump `$(UNTAR_MARKER)` in favor of `tar-contents.mk` and create a valid makefile there which contains a variable definition something like `TAR_CONTENTS = ....` where you fill that in during your untar/etc. processing.